# How to mock moment.locale in Jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, momentjs

I have such overridden properties for localization formats:

```
moment.updateLocale("en", {
  longDateFormat:{l: "MMM D", LTS: "h:mm a"}
});
```

I want to test the function:

```
export function getFormattedDate(date) {
  return moment.unix(date).format("l [at] LTS");
}
```

the test fails with an error:

```
Expected: "May 20 at 2:33 am"
Received: "5/20/2021 at 2:33:28 AM"
```

the jest test:

```
test("Should format date", () => {
  const expected = "May 20 at 2:33 am";
  const result = getFormattedDate(date);
  expect(result).toEqual(expected);
});
```

after I set updateLocale in the test file, the test is passed

```
moment.updateLocale("en", {
  longDateFormat: {l: "MMM D", LTS: "h:mm a"}
});
```

But this looks not good to me to update locale directly in the test. Is there any other way to make tests know about the current locale?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the locale in a `beforeAll()` function in the Jest module is fine.

Keep in mind that the scope of the imported moment object is the test file and tests can run in parallel. So if you have to test multiple locales either use multiple test files or use moment as [isolated module](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/jest-object#jestisolatemodulesfn).

Also make sure the necessary locale file is imported into the test module as well.